# fixing 'Please switch to the gpuarray backend' warning with cuda.use() with keras

Tags: keras, theano

When using

`cuda.use('gpu0')`

I get

`WARNING (theano.sandbox.cuda): The cuda backend is deprecated and will be removed in the next release (v0.10).  Please switch to the gpuarray backend. You can get more information about how to switch at this URL:  https://github.com/Theano/Theano/wiki/Converting-to-the-new-gpu-back-end%28gpuarray%29`

Which is great, but nowhere on the URL do I see anything about using `cuda.use()`.

I tried a variety of combinations:  `theano.sandbox.cuda,use()`, `theano.gpuarray.use()`, `gpuarry.use()`, etc etc and exhausted the combinatoric possibilities. What are we supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

Remove cuda.use and theano.sandbox.cuda. Replace it with this

```
import theano.gpuarray
```

Now go to your .theanorc config file. Should be in ~/.theanorc if linux and change global settings

```
device = cuda0
```

Google around if you can't find theanorc file.